# Performance counters created even if disabled?

Tags: configuration

On my site I discovered that performance counter files are still being created (all 8kb in length with 0 for the values) even though they are disabled, is this normal?

*showconfig.aspx* shows they are indeed disabled. `<setting name="Counters.Enabled" value="false" patch:source="SitecoreSettings.config"/>`

There are over 16,000 of these files in the folder!

I am running Sitecore 8.2 Update 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable the creation of the counters diagnostic files, changing the interval value of the Sitecore agent responsible to dump the performance counter data to `00:00:00`:

```
  <!-- Agent to dump performance counter data -->
  <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CounterDumpAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00">
    <DumpFile>$(dataFolder)/diagnostics/counters.{date}.{time}.{processid}.txt</DumpFile>
  </agent>
```

This agent is defined in the `sitecore.config` configuration file.